# Problem in populating the GridView in ASP.NET(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm trying to populate a `Gridview` with results from loop. But I'm getting only last result in the loop.
I think `GridView` is being overwritten on every time the for loop is being executed.

Can you people help me to remove this problem please.

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    Label1.Text += fipath[j];
    Label1.Text += "-------------";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ILLUMINATI;" + "Database=DB;Integrated Security= true");
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from FileUpload where UploadedBy='" + NAME + "' AND FilePath='" + fipath[j] + "'", conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (Role.Equals("admin"))
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one problem with this code:

- seems like if `Role== "admin"` you don't need to query db at all
- `DataSource` of the grid is overridden on every loop iteration, this is why you see only the last value.
- use parameters for `SqlCommand` to prevent SQL injection.
- don't run string concatenation in the loop. Use `StringBuilder` instead
- use `using` for your connection. The code is cleaner this way.

The fix could look like this:

```
if (Role != "admin")
    return;

var dataTable = new DataTable();
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=ILLUMINATI;" + "Database=DB;Integrated Security= true"))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "Select * from FileUpload where UploadedBy = @UploadedBy AND FilePath = @FilePath";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("UploadedBy", NAME);
    var filPathParameter = command.Parameters.Add("FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(fipath[j]);
        stringBuilder.Append("-------------");
        filPathParameter.Value = fipath[j];
        dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
    }
}
Label1.Text += stringBuilder.ToString();
GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Also, I don't know how many elements your normal loop is. If it is one or two and you have appropriate indexes in `FileUpload` table then it is ok to leave as is. However, if you need to do the for many times you should consider switching to a single query instead

For example:

```
var filePathes = string.Join(",", fipath.Select(arg => "'" + arg + "'"));
var command = "Select * from FileUpload where UploadedBy = @UploadedBy AND FilePath in (" + filePathes + ")";
```

This query is SQL injection prone. And has a 2100 elements limit in MS SQL.

There is more than one way to approach this. Depends on your DBMS and requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` clause in SQL Query and pass the list of ID's in FilePath

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from FileUpload where UploadedBy='" + NAME 
 + "' AND FilePath in (" + listOfIDs + ")", conn);
```

Check out these URLs that are related to the use of `in` clause.

[Techniques for In-Clause and SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/InClauseAndSQLServer.aspx)

[Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

Comment: It looks correct.But for some reason it's not giving any result.

Comment: I removed the for loop and given fipath instead of fipath[j].It's printing nothing.

Comment: You have to give list of Id's in parameter like... in(1,2,3,4) if you have SQL server, simply verify the query there and copy that query in SQL command. Select * from FileUpload where uploadedby='' and Filepath(1,3,4,5)

Answer (score 1):

Create a list or BindingSource outside the loop, bind that to your gridview and then add all records to that list or source.

The problem with your current approach is that you are overwriting the records pulled from the database with a new datasource each time, so as you stated, only the last one is "set", and the older assignments are disposed of.

Comment: How to add items to the list Dynamically.Can you show me please.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: Use the Read method from [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) (your rdr instance) and add an object to a bindingsource for instance using the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.add.aspx) method.